# How to track the big data stored in Gdrive through DVC?

Tags: machine-learning, version-control, mlops, dvc

I am currently working on the ML project and the data size is around 10 GB. The data I stored in google drive. Its impossible for me to download it on my local machine. So, how to use the DVC (data version control) to track that data? Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi Vedant, could you please give us a bit more context - what it the nature of the data (images, text, one file, many files?), how do you process it/train (download? stream from), what is the use case for DVC here, what do you want to achieve with it?